# Cross domain jquery ajax api call with custom headers is not hitting the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain

I want to call a webservice from client side using jquery ajax(with custom headers). And I almost did that. I had set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to force.com and salesforce.com since I'm calling the webservice from salesforce.

When I try to call that API without the custom headers, its getting the response where as when I called with the headers, its not getting the response.

With custom headers

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    url: 'https://xxx.myclient.com/xxx/xxx/register',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('orgid', '00D90000000oxxxx');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('userid', '00590000001Dxxxxxx');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success' + JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('jqXHR : ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ' textStatus : ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

also tried with

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    url: 'https://xxx.myclient.com/xxx/xxx/register',
    headers: {
        "orgid": "00D90000000oxxxx",
        "userid": "00590000001Dxxxxxx",
    },

    success: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('jqXHR : ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ' textStatus : ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

But in both the above cases it is not hitting the server and getting the error message

[image]

[image]
When I'm not using any headers, then its hitting the server

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    url: 'https://xxx.myclient.com/xxx/xxx/register',
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success' + JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('jqXHR : ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ' textStatus : ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

Its getting the success response
[image]

In response headers it shows that

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Only content-type is there, Is that the problem? 
Whether we need to add our custom headers here?

And when I analysed the network using firefox firebug, it is showing as given below
[image]

1. POST Register (without any headers passed)
2. OPTIONS Register (with custom headers)

I dont know why this is happening

Can any one help.

Thanks in Advance ..:)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding your custom headers (orgId and userId) in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" list of the service you are calling.